# Dual boot ubuntu 11.04 and fedora 15

Tags: grub2, fedora

I want make dual boot with feodra 15 and ubuntu 11.04 for testing features,please guide me the same.
         i had done dual boot with windows and linux but not linux linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may check this article: [Dual-boot Fedora 15 and Ubuntu 11.04 with either side on an LVM partitioning scheme](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/06/20/dual-boot-fedora-15-and-ubuntu-11-04-with-either-side-on-an-lvm-partitioning-scheme/) It very detail article. Hope this help.

GRUB boot menu:

[image: GRUB boot menu]

Create Custom Layout:

[image: Create Custom Layout]

Comment: +1 upvote - that's great and very detailed answer, I had learned something new :) Actually it was very interesting for me as well, because I'm planning to install Fedora in the nearest future(alongside with Natty)

Answer (score 1):

I have dual-boot with Ubuntu 11.04 and Ubuntu 10.10.

I assume that one of Linux OS has been already installed on your PC.

When you start installation, it should ask if you want to add Ubuntu(or in your case Fedora) alongside.

If you choose this option, it will give you opportunity to specify how big partition you would like to get(shrink) for new OS (Fedora or Ubuntu 11.04.)

Then after installation you can change preferences of Startup Manager and specify which OS will be as default