# How to dual booting ubuntu 11.10 and fedora 16?

Tags: dual-boot, fedora

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dual boot ubuntu 11.04 and fedora 15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62378/dual-boot-ubuntu-11-04-and-fedora-15)

I installed ubuntu 11.10 on my system.

I tried to install fedora 16 on free space I have left for it. when after completing installation and rebooting I saw boot menu with fedora only .

Is there any possibility of getting a resolution to this issue?.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion (I use when I have not time to search) is to install the second os bootloader on the partition table (not in MBR) and redirect unto it from the first bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dual-boot with Fedora, you should install Fedora first since Ubuntu's GRUB picks up all operating Systems on your computer but Fedora's GRUB sometimes doesn't.  But since you have Ubuntu installed first, follow these steps to get Ubuntu's grub back:

1. Boot from a Ubuntu live CD or USB.
2. Download [Boot-Repair](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/) and run it.

[image]

3. Select "Recommended repair" and Reboot.  You should see UBuntu's GRUB with Fedora and Ubuntu.

If you see the Ubuntu GRUB but did not see Fedora, boot into Ubuntu and open the terminal.  Then type `sudo update-grub` in the terminal and reboot.  Fedora will show.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I always run this command after installing Windows XP and Debian 6.0 on my computer, because for some reason my Debian 6.0 do not recognize the Windows XP on the boot menu.

```
sudo update-grub
```